# Rendering HTML partials within JSON ERB Template Correctly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been struggling to get the following to work in my Rails 4 application; I'm trying to return a JSON response from a search API which has some generated HTML in the returned objects:

```
## Controller code
...
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.haml
  format.json # index.json.erb
end

## JSON view code
[
  <% @results.each do |result| %>
  {
    "type": "<%= result.type -%>",
    "content": "<%= escape_javascript render partial: "search/#{result.type}", formats: :html, locals: { result: result } %>"
  }<%= ',' unless result == @results.last %>
  <% end %>
]
```

The resulting code looks correctly escaped and successfully validates in various online JSON validators when I execute a JSON request to the search URL, yet jQuery refuses to fire the getJSON's callback function.

If I remove the `content` section the callback fires just fine, so I know it's something to do with the partial rendering.

Any pointers greatly appreciated. As mentioned above, I've worked through a number of suggested solutions in other Stack Overflow questions and not had any joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to suggest using native `to_json` method against manually creating the json:

```
<%=raw  @results.map do |result|
          { "type" => result.type,
            "content" => render(partial: "search/#{result.type}", formats: :html, locals: { result: result }) }
    end.to_json %>
```

Comment: This got me closer - thanks. It ended up being as you say above, but without `escape_javascript` and with `raw` on the whole block.

Comment: I forgot about the `raw`, of course it is necessary. I also updated the answer following your comment to be fully correct.